# Can't get the customized portion of few strings

Tags: string, vba, excel

I've written a script in vba to get the customized portion of certain strings.

What I want is get the portion within `first` and `last` part of a string. It works only when the to-be kicked out part doesn't resemble any of the remaining portions.

I've tried like below:

```
Sub GetCustomizedString()
    Dim stritm As Variant, strsplit As Variant, snum$, lpart$, midpart$, sname$, I&

    For Each stritm In [{"7409 KIM HKND DP ND","9793 ANTHONY JONES HO NE","5089 TIM PETER XM"}]

        strsplit = Split(stritm, " ")
        I = UBound(strsplit)
        snum = strsplit(0)  'get the first portion of each string
        lpart = strsplit(I) 'get the last portion of each string
        midpart = Replace(stritm, snum, "") 'get the rest after the first portion
        sname = Trim(Replace(midpart, lpart, ""))
        Debug.Print sname

    Next stritm
End Sub
```

It yeilds the following output:

```
KIM HK DP
ANTHONY JOS HO
TIM PETER
```

Whereas my expected output is:

```
KIM HKND DP
ANTHONY JONES HO
TIM PETER
```

> ***To be clearer:*** If I try on this string `5089 TIM PETER XM`, it works parfectly and gives me `TIM PETER` as output.
>   But when I try on this `7409 KIM HKND DP ND` then the result becomes messier and it gives me `KIM HK DP` as output. It happens because `ND` is also within `HKND`. So the `replace` function kicks them all irrespective of it's position.

Comment: If you just concatenate from and including element lbound+1 (which skips first elements) to ubound-1 (which skips last element), does that reliably give you your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub tester()

    Dim itm, n
    For Each itm In Array("7409 KIM HKND DP ND", "9793 ANTHONY JONES HO NE", _
                         "5089 TIM PETER XM")

        n = Right(itm, Len(itm) - InStr(itm, " "))
        n = Left(n, InStrRev(n, " "))

        Debug.Print Trim(n)

    Next

End Sub
```

output:

```
KIM HKND DP
ANTHONY JONES HO
TIM PETER
```

Comment: It perfectly did the job @Tim. Can you clarify this `InStrRev` in comment. Thanks.

Comment: I could not understand why your solution got a downvote whereas it worked perfectly in my several strings.

Comment: InStrRev - "in string (reverse)" - find the *last* instance of space in the string

Answer (score 1):

With regex

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetCustomizedString()
    Dim stritm As Variant
    For Each stritm In [{"7409 KIM HKND DP ND","9793 ANTHONY JONES HO NE","5089 TIM PETER XM"}]
        Debug.Print GetString(stritm)
    Next stritm
End Sub
Public Function GetString(ByVal inputString As String) As Variant
    Dim arr() As String, I As Long, matches As Object, re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "(^\w+[^\S](.*)\s)([^\s\s]+$)"
        If .test(inputString) Then
            GetString = .Execute(inputString)(0).submatches(1)
        Else
            GetString = inputString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Regex:**

[image: Regex]

*[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/pKf4vA/1)*